# Updating some fields that occurs in multiple table at once in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables `employee` and `wage`:

The `employee` table consists columns: `idEmployeeGlobal`, `email`, `position`, `idEmployeeWorkingLocation`.

The table `wage` consists columns: `idWage`, `wage`, `idEmployeeGlobal`, `idEmployeeWorkingLocation`.

In this situation, **I can't change the database.** It always error occurred when updating those two tables. The error is

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Here is my code to update:

```php
// Employee Section
$employee = Employee::find($id);
$employee->idEmployeeWorkingLocation = $request->idEmployeeWorkingLocation;
$employee->email = $request->email;
$employee->position = $request->position;
$employee->save();

// Wage Section
$wage = Wage::where('idEmployeeGlobal', $id)->first();
$wage->idEmployeeLocation = $request->idEmployeeLocation;
$wage->save();
```

No matter whether the position of Wage Section or the Employee section in code above, I always ended up in error.

I also can't get the full error because my working place prohibits telling any company resources outside.

Case Example:

This is **John Doe**, He works in New York (15) then he gets moved to London (51). There is changes in the field `idEmployeeWorkingLocation`, `position`, and `wage` that is needed to be inputted by admin.

Before update

```
// Employee Table
idEmployeeGlobal |        email        | position | idEmployeeWorkingLocation
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1       | johndoe@example.com | Manager  | 15

// Wage Table
idWage |  wage  | idEmployeeGlobal (FK) | idEmployeeWorkingLocation (FK)
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
   1   |  $50   | 1                     | 15
```

Desired result after change:
Before update

```
// Employee Table
idEmployeeGlobal |        email        | position   | idEmployeeWorkingLocation
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1       | johndoe@example.com | Head of HR | 51

// Wage Table
idWage |  wage  | idEmployeeGlobal (FK) | idEmployeeWorkingLocation (FK)
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
   1   |  $55   | 1                     | 51
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your table structure for employee and wage tables? The main issue is there is some primary key in one table which references the foreign key in the child table. Most probably that is idEmployeeLocation. But need table structure to verify that.

Comment: My supervisor disallow me to share such table structure/migrations.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using transactions?

Comment: Have you checked putting the 2 sections in different transactions? means one after the other?

Comment: I put both in one transaction

Comment: I am asking you to put in a different transaction. First, update employee row and commit then update wage row in other transaction and commit. Then check if the error is resolved

Comment: Could you please elaborate it in your answer? Won't it cause any data integrity problem because the difference between tables when updating the another one failed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have record for this `idEmployeeGlobal` in your wages table. Make sure the record is created.

Also share your migration files for the wages and employees table.

---

**Use cases to debug** 
To check if you are getting wage

```
$wage = Wage::where('idEmployeeGlobal', $id)->first();
dd($wage)
```

To check if you are getting input from form

```
dd($request->idEmployeeLocation);
```

Comment: I have it. it's shown in my question and also I had checked it. My supervisor does not allow me to share migrations

Comment: Do you have the record for this employee which you are updating in wages table?

Comment: Sure. I will add it up in the question

Comment: You can check it yourself, just check if you have record for that $id which you are updating for

Comment: Friend you have to check every use case by dd(), I will tell you how can you check